# Caliburn.Micro - Setting focus in new window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

My application is a topmost `Window` switching between multiple `UserControl` views. Its behavior is to close when the user clicks outside the window (more generally when it loses focus), and to show again when the user clicks on the system tray icon.

I'm having trouble getting the window to get focus when it shows up after clicking the tray icon. The problem is that the window shows up without focus and it doesn't hide when the user clicks outside. The user has to first click into the window and then click outside to trigger the Window's `Deactivated` event.

I can reproduce the problem with the most basic example from the documentation. I'm showing below the most basic representation of the problem I could produce.

I have tried many different things, none of which have shown any different behavior. For example, I tried calling the view's `Focus()` in the OnViewLoaded handler in the view models and deactivating the viewmodels instead of closing the window in the `Close` action. I also tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343304/caliburn-micro-showpopup-set-focus) on what seemed to be the same problem.

Any hint or help as to how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Export(typeof(ShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    IWindowManager windowManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;

        ShowPageOne();
    }

    public void ShowPageOne()
    {
        ActivateItem(new PageOneViewModel());
    }

    public void ShowPageTwo()
    {
        ActivateItem(new PageTwoViewModel());
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.TryClose();

        // Using this to simulate the user clicking on a system tray icon
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            windowManager.ShowWindow(this);
            timer.Stop();
        };
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

My ShellView is:

```
<Window x:Class="PopupTest.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:tc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
         xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
         Width="300" Height="400"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event Deactivated] = [Action Close]"
         Topmost="True">

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="ShowPageOne" Content="Show Page One" />
        <Button x:Name="ShowPageTwo" Content="Show Page Two" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</StackPanel>
```

My two view models are:

```
public class PageOneViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.Screen { }

public class PageTwoViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.Screen { }
```

And the views are:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PopupTest.PageOneView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <TextBlock x:Name="bob" FontSize="32">Page One</TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I was building an application similar to yours and had the same problem but didn't look deep to find a solution, it seems like the managed API's such as calling `Focus()` and the rest doesn't do the job, and searching a bit I **think** the un-managed API can do the job. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14525600/439667).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Following links, I ended up on this blog [link](http://blog.jorgearimany.com/2010/10/win32-setforegroundwindow-equivalent-in.html) that suggested to simply call view.Activate(). It works for my simple demo code!
For my actual app, this problem was intermittent. It hasn't reproed so far, but I'll wait some time before confirming it fixes it.